# Get a String from a JSon request

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, httpwebrequest

i'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Scala.
I'm writing a Statistic controller that queries my mongodb database for obtain some informations.
Now i'm trying to implement a method that returns all the tags associate to a user.
I get an http request in json format as the following:

```
{
  "user": "example@example.com"
}
```

I want to parse the Json request and get the String associate to the "user" field of the Json, if the Json is correctly i want to do some work with the String object, otherwise i want to return a BadRequest response.

My method implementation is something like this:

```
def userEmail = Action.async { request =>
         val userEmail: String = request.body.asJson.map { json =>
                        json.validate[String].map {
                          //if the json congaing the "user tag" return the instance, get the instance, otherwise return a BadRequestInstance

                        }

         }
       def elaborate(user: String)= {
        //some work
       }
       elaborate(userEmail)
}
```

How can i make that??

Comment: Read the documentation! https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson

Comment: I solved using \ "user" and cast the JsonString to a String object using as[String], thanks.
I search in the documentation before, but i don't find any response, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  [johanandren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219125/johanandren) mentioned reading [playframework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson) documentation should solve your problem.

Hint: I would define case class and implicit reads to convert json data into case class type.

```scala
case class User(email: String)
```

```scala
implicit val userReads = (
    (JsPath \ "email").read[String]
)(User.apply _)
```